# sql : how to get the sum of sums

Tags: sql, sum

The below I can get the result of sub_shares, but I don't know how to get the result sum(sub_shares) by using the result of sub_shares for the below code:

How to do ?

```html
SELECT * , 
Client.client_chi_name, 
Client.client_eng_name, 
SUM( shares_no ) AS sub_shares
FROM Shareholder
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
WHERE Shareholder.com_no = 2040628
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id
ORDER BY SUM( shares_no ) DESC,
Shareholder.date_of_register DESC
```

**Table Shareholder**

- com_no
- date_of_register
- share_type
- class_shares
- client_id
- shares_no
- transferee_id
- currency
- shares_amount

Thank you very much for your help & support.

Comment: Just for reference, is it a particular RDBMS you're looking for an answer to, or just a generic SQL way?

Comment: Which database you refer i.e. sqlserver, oracle, mysql etc?

Answer (score 1):

you can use CTE (Commom Table Expression) to accomplish the same task

```
with cte as
(
SELECT * , 
Client.client_chi_name, 
Client.client_eng_name, 
SUM( shares_no ) AS sub_shares
FROM Shareholder
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
WHERE Shareholder.com_no = 2040628
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id
ORDER BY shares_no  DESC,
Shareholder.date_of_register DESC
)

select cte.client_chi_name,cte.client_eng_name,SUM(cte.sub_shares) sub_shares from cte   --you can access more column which is present in * 
GROUP BY client_chi_name,client_eng_name --place extra column yor are accessing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * , 
  Client.client_chi_name, 
  Client.client_eng_name, 
  SUM( shares_no ) AS sub_shares,
  (select sum(shares_no) FROM Shareholder
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
      WHERE Shareholder.com_no = 2040628) as sum_of_sum
FROM Shareholder
LEFT OUTER JOIN Client ON Shareholder.client_id = Client.client_id
WHERE Shareholder.com_no = 2040628
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id
ORDER BY SUM( shares_no ) DESC,
Shareholder.date_of_register DESC
```

You can add just one more column with subselect

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast help !

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code as per your need,

either

```
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id WITH ROLLUP
```

or

```
GROUP BY Shareholder.client_id WITH CUBE
```

For detail understanding, please refer [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to rewrite it, can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove your GROUP BY and do the following:

```
SUM( shares_no ) OVER (PARTITION BY Client.client_id) AS sub_shares
SUM( shares_no ) AS total_shares,
```

You'd also need to start with SELECT DISTINCT or you'd get duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to rewrite it, can you help ?

Comment: Your query stays exactly the same, except 1) the first line should say SELECT DISTINCT 2) replace your line that starts with SUM with my above code and 3) remove your line that starts with GROUP BY

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to rewrite it ?